# TcpClient - what I can replace it with?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

We have client-server application where all clients also talk to each other via TCP (TcpClient + TcpListener on each client)

So, when client A does something - it sends message to clients B, C and D and then waits for response. This get's kind of slow with many clients (like 20 now) Especially when clien B dies - client A waits for until times out.

Is there any better way maybe broadcast package to everyone at the same time? I know everybody's host names, etc.

I just need to send message and know if they did/didn't receive it successfully.

What my options are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to completely switch off the strategy and use some message bus that does this in a reliable and performance tuned way. I'm happy with [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), that even if it is implemented in Java [works in C# very easily](http://rantdriven.com/post/ActiveMQ-via-C-sharp-and-dotnet-using-ApacheNMS-Part-1.aspx). If you want something pure .NET take a look at [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) or [Rhino Service bus](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-service-bus). I know that you probably feel the task of dispatching message between client is easy and you can do it yourself, if you want to do reliable in production is better if you leverage the someone else effort and relax yourself. It will be very frustrating trying to solve communications bugs when the app run at the customer site. Ignore this if you are writing a competitor message bus, of course :)
All these solutions allow you to have the Job done by just the effort of reading the documentation. Do some test app "in vitro" before going to replace the production code just to gain the necessary confidence, and then replace the hard TcpClient. I'm quite sure you can find a truncate point to insulate just the message datagrams where place the new strategy on.

Comment: If all the clients run Windows, you could use MSMQ which is (an optional) part of the OS.

Comment: @Colin Desmond yes, this is true, but MSMQ queues are just fifo and you need some effort to create a dispatch strategy ( broadcast )

Comment: I see what you saying. At this point app os in support mode only, so changes should be minimal. And I definitely don't want to add anymore server infrastructure.

Comment: If changes should be minimal, I wouldn't try to replace TcpClient. This sounds like a major change.

Comment: @katit I agree with Patrik, even changing from Tcp to semthing else it is an impacting change, maybe the one I suggested is less impacting

Answer (score 0):

You can use multicast protocol where you only need to send one packet to your group.

Comment: Can you give me more details on what exactly multicast protocol and maybe some .NET example?